# limits of natural log

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{w\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\ln{w^2}}{\ln{w^3}+1}$

This particular limit is giving me trouble. Am I correct that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}(\ln{f(x)})=\ln{\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow a}}f(x)$? That is the approach I took but it didn't seem to help. I must have a hole in my understanding here because I can't figure out how to proceed. Any hints or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: $$
\frac{\log w^2}{\log w^3+1} = \frac{2\log w}{3\log w+1} \stackrel{w\to\infty}\longrightarrow\frac23.
$$

Comment: "Am I correct that limx→a(lnf(x))=lnlimx→af(x)?"  Only if 1) $f(x)$ is continuous and 2) $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ exists and is finite.  1) is okay but 2) fails.  So you can't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I correct that limx→a(lnf(x))=lnlimx→af(x)?

Unfortunately not if $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \infty$ which is the case here.

$\ln w^k = k\ln w$ so replace $\ln w$ with $v$ and you have

$\lim_{w\to \infty}\frac {\ln w^2}{\ln w^3 + 1} =\lim_{w\to \infty} \frac {2\ln w}{3\ln w^3 + 1}=\lim_{e^v\to \infty}\frac {2v}{3v + 1}$

Can you do that?

Comment: If $f(x)\to\infty$ then $\ln(f(x))\to\infty$. The only problem then (for this particular question) is that we'd get $\frac\infty\infty$.

Comment: We'd get $\frac \infty \infty$ only if we did the $\lim f(x) = f(\lim x) $ trick which we can not do.  I'm leaving it to the reader to come up with the correct way to do this.  Thing is, well, the limit in terms of logs may not be immediately apparent, I am hoping that the limit of a quotient of linear expressions is fairly familiar enough for the reader to figure out.

Comment: ... any way  $\lim_{e^v\to \infty} f(v) = \lim_{v\to \infty} f(v)$ becase both $e^v$ and $v\to \infty$  And $\lim \frac {2v}{3v+1} = \lim \frac {2}{3+\frac 1v}$ and now you *CAN* do $\lim f(x) = f(\lim x)$ as $\lim \frac 1v =0$ which is finite.  Or you can do a fairly standard delta-epsilon proof.  Heck, I'd even accept a hoary "as $v$ becomes large the $1$ becomes insignificant" argument (provided the student can back it up with cases from the text that laid precedence).